# Solving an 2nd order ODE with internal conditions - Matlab

Tags: matlab, time, conditional-statements, ode, acceleration

I have this 2nd order ODE to solve in Matlab:

```
(a + f(t))·(dx/dt)·(d²x/dt²)  +  g(t)  +  ((h(t) + i(t)·(d²x/dt² > b·(c-x)))·(dx/dt)  +  j(t))·(dx/dt)²  +  k(t)·(t > d)  = 0
```

where

- `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` are known constants
- `f(t)`,`g(t)`,`h(t)`,`i(t)`,`j(t)`,`k(t)` are known functions dependent on `t`
- `x` is the position
- `dx/dt` is the velocity
- `d²x/dt²` is the acceleration

and notice the two conditions that

- `i(t)` is introduced in the equation if `(d²x/dt² > b·(c-x))`
- `k(t)` is introduced in the equation if `(t > d)`

So, the problem could be solved with a similar structure in Matlab as this example:

```
[T,Y] = ode45(@(t,y) [y(2); 'the expression of the acceleration'], tspan, [x0 v0]);
```

where

- `T` is the time vector,  `Y` is the vector of position (column 1 as `y(1)`) and velocity (column 2 as `y(2)`).
- `ode45` is the ODE solver, but another one could be used.
- `tspan`,`x0`,`v0` are known.
- `the expression of the acceleration` means an expression for `d²x/dt²`, but **here comes the problem, since it is inside the condition for `i(t)` and 'outside' at the same time multiplying `(a + f(t))·(dx/dt)`**. So, the acceleration cannot be written in matlab as `d²x/dt² = something`

Some issues that could help:

- once the condition `(d²x/dt² > b·(c-x))` and/or `(t > d)` is satisfied, the respective term `i(t)` and/or `k(t)` will be introduced until the end of the determined time in `tspan`.
- for the condition `(d²x/dt² > b·(c-x))`, the term `d²x/dt²` could be written as the difference of velocities, like `y(2) - y(2)'`, if `y(2)'` is the velocity of the previous instant, divided by the step-time defined in `tspan`. But I do not know **how to access the previous value of the velocity *during* the solving of the ODE**

Thank you in advanced !

Comment: Use [event location](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html) to stop and start the solver based on your conditions – this is exactly what that feature is meant for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention

> ode45 is the ODE solver, but another one could be used.

And your concern (it seems to me) is having access to the history such that you can evaluate `d^2x/dt^2` yourself, to introduce the new conditions, have you considered looking into `dde23` (delayed diffeq)?

From the documentation, you specify a vector of lag times yourself, and have the option to specify history as "...the previous solution from an integration, if this call continues that integration" https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dde23.html.

Hopefully this is helpful since, at the very least you should be able to make a workaround by wrapping your own function that returns the values from the dde23 solutions and check the point you should introduce the new conditions yourself, and then specify the new function, compiling your results as necessary, essentially reducing the problem into more steps.

Comment: Try running `edit ddx1` in the command window.  It will bring up a good example function with some sub-functions specifying the history function as well as ddex1de (in their example).  That should clear up the implementation details.  Then, you should be able to define (ddex1de in example) function to actually check your condition using the parameters, and then return a new diffeq with your introduced terms (essentially modifying the ddyt array in the example). Then, at that iteration the new set of terms should be introduced.  Let me know if this is making sense.